# Cast to string failed for value "[ 'Electrician', 'Active' ]" at path "work" for model "User"

Tags: string, mongodb, search

Error logs:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Server running on port 5000
CastError: Cast to string failed for value "[ 'Electrician', 'Active' ]" at path "work" for
model "User"
    at model.Query.exec (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New Horizon\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4437:21)
    at model.Query.Query.find (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New Horizon\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2050:8)
    at Function.find (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New Horizon\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2070:13)
    at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New Horizon\app.js:415:12
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New Horizon\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New Horizon\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at ensureAuthenticated (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New Horizon\app.js:19:14)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New Horizon\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)    at next (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New Horizon\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New Horizon\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New Horizon\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New Horizon\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New Horizon\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New Horizon\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)    at methodOverride (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New Horizon\node_modules\method-override\index.js:65:14)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New Horizon\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5) {
  messageFormat: undefined,  stringValue: `"[ 'Electrician', 'Active' ]"`,
  kind: 'string',  value: [ 'Electrician', 'Active' ],
  path: 'work',  reason: null
}
```

The code :

```
app.get('/search',ensureAuthenticated,(req,res)=>{
  try {
      User.find({$or:[{work:{'$regex':req.query.dsearch}},
{status:{'$regex':req.query.dsearch}}
]},(err,user)=>{

      if(err){
        // req.flash('error', 'Employee  not founded .')
        console.log(err);
        console.log('Finding book');

      }
      else{
        // req.flash('success_msg', 'Finding Employee ... ');
        res.render('result',{user:user});
        // console.log(user);

      }
    })
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
          }
    });
```